# Argcd application generated via applicationsets are not visible in UI

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to create applications in argocd using application sets and also i am using apps of apps pattern.

Here is  `root-app-dev.yaml`

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: root-appbundle-app-dev
  namespace: argocd
  finalizers:
  - resources-finalizer.argocd.argoproj.io
spec:
  destination:
    namespace: default
    name: in-cluster
  project: appbundle-project-dev
  syncPolicy:
    automated: {} 
  source:
    path: argocd/apps-children/dev
    repoURL: https://github.com/<username>/argocd-root
    targetRevision: HEAD
```

And the applicationSet manifest located in the  `argocd/apps-children/dev` folder

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: ApplicationSet
metadata:
  name: child-app-template
spec:
  goTemplate: true
  goTemplateOptions: ["missingkey=error"]
  generators:
  - matrix:
      generators:
      - git:
          repoURL: https://github.com/shamonshan/argocd-root
          revision: HEAD
          files:
          - path: configs/config.yml
      - list:
          elements: []
          elementsYaml: "{{ .configs.components | toJson }}"
  template:
    metadata:
      name: '{{.name}}'
    spec:
      project: '{{.project}}'
      destination:
        name: in-cluster
        namespace: '{{.namespace}}'
      source:
        repoURL: '{{.repoUrl}}'
        path : helm
        targetRevision: '{{.version}}'
```

Applied the manifest using  `kubectl apply -f argocd/root-app-dev.yml`
and i can see the parent application in the argocd UI but the applications that are created by the applicationsSet is not visible in the UI.

[image: Current UI]

Also no resources related  are created in the cluster as well

Comment: This means that the ApplicationSet is not generating any Applications. You can also double check in logs of the ApplicationSet controller.

Comment: can you share the command details if possible i m new to k8s :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ApplicationSet if something like wrong templating occurs during the generating of the applications, the apps will not be generated :)
you can see what's wrong with the applicationSet using this command

```
kubectl describe applicationsets.argoproj.io -n argocd child-app-template
```

If you need further help please provide us with the output.

Comment: Thanks its  help me to resolve the issue, the issue with namespace

Comment: Could you please have  look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77690532/argocd-matrix-generator-map-has-no-entry-for-key-config